# Swift 5 - UrlSession - Post request starts with array

Tags: swift

I am new about Swift. And I have question.I have to post a request starts with an array.

like this:

```
[{"columnName":"","columnLogic":"LIKE","columnValue":""}]
```

I tried with postman and return value which I wanted to.

Normally if it doesn't start with "[" and then I can post request and get back value. But Start with "[" and I tried many things not succeded :( please help me! I add my code which I use starts with "{" json post, this codes return error.`

```
private func getDataCars(){
    
    struct Result: Codable {
        let status: String
        let document: DocumentStruct
    }
    
    struct DocumentStruct : Codable {
        let pageno: Int
        let total_count: String
        let records: [RecordStruct]
    }
    
    
    struct RecordStruct: Codable{
     
        let  user_id:String
        let  user_name:String      
        let  user_mail:String
        let user_password:String
        let user_phone:String
        let user_durum:String
       
    }
    
    let parameters = [["columnName": "nameofcolumn", "columnLogic": "LIKE", "columnValue": "searchstring"]]
    let url = URL(string: "http://getapiadress")!
    let AuthTokenString = "somekey"
    let session = URLSession.shared
           var request = URLRequest(url: url)
           request.httpMethod = "POST"
           request.addValue("Bearer " + AuthTokenString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    
    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to data object and set it as request body
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        
    }

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil else {return}
    guard let data = data else {return}
    var result: Result?
                    do{
                          result=try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)
                      }
                      catch{
                          print("failed")
                          print(error)
                      }
                      
                      guard let json = result else {
                          return
                      }
    
        print(json.document.records[0].car_marka)
       
    })
        task.resume()
           
}`
```

here is my response of post request:

```
{
"status": "success",
"code": 1,
"message": "users found",
"document": {
    "pageno": "1",
    "pagesize": "30",
    "total_count": "1",
    "records": [
        {
            "user_id": "1",
            "user_name": "Boss",
            "user_mail": "boss@boss.com",
            "user_password": "boss",
            "user_phone": "123456789",
            "user_durum": "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Just to clarify. You need the body of the request to be `{"columnName":"","columnLogic":"LIKE","columnValue":""}`?

Comment: With "[ ]" My sending post like; [{"columnName":"","columnLogic":"LIKE","columnValue":""}]

Comment: `let parameters = ["columnName": "nameofcolumn", "columnLogic": "LIKE", "columnValue": "searchstring"]` -> `let parameters = [["columnName": "nameofcolumn", "columnLogic": "LIKE", "columnValue": "searchstring"]]`? Currently `parameters` is a Dictionary, but if you need it to be an Array, then make it an array.

Comment: with this line ` let parameters = [["columnName": "car_durum", "columnLogic": "LIKE", "columnValue": "admin"]]` I get this error typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "document", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Your error is then in the decoding, no? Because of `result=try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)`, but it's then not related to the sent parameters. And it's saying that `let document: DocumentStruct` is wrong. But we can't guess exactly what, if you don't show the response of the request.

Comment: I added response of post request.

Comment: last update works. 
`[["columnName": "nameofcolumn", "columnLogic": "LIKE", "columnValue": "searchstring"]]` problem not posting code problem was in decode code. Thanks o lot @burnsi @Larme

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a dictionary as you mentioned at the beginning but you get a run-time error while trying to declare a JSON variable in XCode

```
[{"columnName":"","columnLogic":"LIKE","columnValue":""}]
```

Then in your code, you can do like this

```
// this is the dictionary format in Swift 
let parameters = ["columnName": "","columnLogic": "LIKE","columnValue": ""]

 do {
     // This step will convert your dictionary to jsonData
     let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)
     request.httpBody = jsonData
 } catch let error {
     print(error.localizedDescription)
        
 }
```

BUT Then if you want to make a POST request with an Array of objects then you can do something like this

```
struct ColumnInfo: Codable {
   let columnName: String
   let columnLogic: String
   let columnValue: String
}
   
let parameters = [ColumnInfo(columnName: "nameofcolumn", columnLogic: "LIKE", columnValue: "searchstring")]

let url = URL(string: "http://getapiadress")!
let AuthTokenString = "somekey"
let session = URLSession.shared
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("Bearer " + AuthTokenString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    
do {
   let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
   jsonEncoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
   request.httpBody = try jsonEncoder.encode(parameters) // pass dictionary to data object and set it as request body
} catch let error {
   print(error.localizedDescription)        
}
```